# Azure Function debug connection from Visual Studio 2017 getting a 'N/A' listener connection error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I start a new project in Visual Studio 2017 (with the latest updates) and create a Azure Function.  I added the storage account to both the local.settings.json and paste in the connection string from for the Storage account into AzureWebJobsStorage.

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static void Run([EventHubTrigger("wms-events", Connection = "ConnectionStringTest1")]string myEventHubMessage, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info($"C# Event Hub trigger function processed a message: {myEventHubMessage}");
    }
```

> The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start.  Microsoft.ServiceBuss:  An error occurred during communication with 'N/A'.  Check the connection information, then retry.  System:  An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Why 'N/A'?  I would have assumed that was the WebStorage connection and I know that is a legit connection string.

[image]

Connection string example (obfuscated)

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=stuff;AccountKey=UCIdr7FscQQIJhRkJ4rsstuffstuffstuffzKwRZ1QG4EC9bIhJx+x11CVg9dd1AElMBUkw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=stuffstuffstuff;AccountKey=UCIdr7FscQQIJhRkstuffstuffstuff3/zZ5FyGJ3MdzKwRZ1QG4EC9bIhJx+x11CVg9dd1AElMBUkw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "ConnectionStringTest1": "Endpoint=sb://stuffstuffstuff.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=AzureFunction;SharedAccessKey=SVfahzJQE5ustuffstuffstuff1zrgAOUPI+yfp63pRA=;EntityPath=stuffstuffstuff"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you set your `ConnectionStringTest1` in local.settings.json?

Comment: yes, that is the copy/pasted string from the service bus and AzureWebJobsStorage is the storage account.

Comment: I was able to get a normal Http Trigger to debug, so maybe related to the Service bus only?

Comment: Can you add your local app settings to this question? Obviously obfuscate any sensitive data but let us see the basic structure

Comment: Added this to the question @JesseCarter

Comment: can you please check NuGet package version for Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus in you VS solution. Also you do not need to reference ServiceBus package directly.

Comment: WebJobs version 2.1.0 beta1

Answer (score 0):

How did you get ConnectionStringTest1? It should be eventhub connection string(not service bus). You can get connection string on evenhub namespace or eventhub level using Shared Access Policies on the portal:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-create

Comment: Yeah, it is the EventHub address.  I copied it from the EventHub Shared Access Policies section. 
 removed any sensitive data from it: 
 Endpoint=sb://<stuff>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=AzureFunction;SharedAccessKey=SVfahzJQE5uqOdaf3DF3241zrgAOUPI+yfp63pRA=;EntityPath=<stuff>

Comment: Do you have "Manage", "Send", "Listen" checked for "AzureFunction" policy? Is "AzureFunction" eventhub namespace policy or eventhub policy?

Comment: it has "Listen" in the policy

Comment: Did you try to publish your function to the cloud and see if it works? Did you to link your trigger with with another newly created event hub?

Comment: yeah, when i push to the cloud it works, I just can't locally debug

Comment: So I think it's some kind of networking issue and not Azure Function issue. You can try another machine/network.